# ¿Es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores? C++

Tags: c++, poo, dev-c++

En POO se usa mucho lo que son los constructores (ya sea ponerlo vacíos y luego hacer una sobrecarga de constructores, o por otra parte, usar los getters y setters).

En varios videos, he visto que cuando usa setters y getters ya no es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores (asumiendo así que el programa solo los crea y solo se destruye), pero, por otra parte, también he visto que cuando  usan los setters y Getters igualmente escriben los constructores y destructores pero dejándolos vacío.

Y aquí viene mi confusión: es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores cuando usamos setters o getters?

Comment: Saludos. Sí, es preferible invertir tiempo en escribirlo; constructor: allí inicializas cada tipo de dato y objeto, destructor: liberas explicitamente de forma segura lo usado. Lo que dices como Setters y Getters; basicamente todo objeto tiene su forma de obtener y establecer valor.

Answer (score 4):

**Funciones implementadas automáticamente**

El compilador de C++ es capaz de crear ciertas funciones especiales por si mismo:

- Constructor por defecto
- Constructor copia
- Constructor copia (semántica de movimiento)
- Destructor
- Operador de asignación
- Operador de asignación (semántica de movimiento)

Existen, no obstante, reglas que determinan cuándo va el compilador a implementar estas funciones. Así, por ejemplo, el constructor por defecto solo será implementado por el compilador cuando no se haya declarado ningún constructor personalizado.

**Memoria dinámica**

Por otro lado, aunque el compilador nos genere estas funciones, hay que tener en cuenta que esto no implica que su trabajo vaya a ser correcto... o al menos como esperamos. El compilador no se preocupa de la memoria dinámica, si nuestra clase tiene un puntero, la función generada se limitará a copiar la dirección de memoria, lo que puede darnos problemas en algunas ocasiones.

De la misma manera, el destructor **nunca** llamará a `delete` para liberar la memoria asociada a un puntero.

**Implementación de las funciones automáticas**

Un tercer factor a tener en cuenta es que cuando el compilador genera una función automáticamente, la implementa a nivel de cabecera. Esto nos limita muchísimo a la hora de usar *declaration forward*, lo que aumentará los tiempos de compilación.

**Implementación de funciones automáticas (C++11)**

A partir de C++11 es posible forzar la implementación automática de una función. Simplemente tendremos que añadir `= default` detrás de la función:

```
class POO
{
public:
  // Este constructor evita que el compilador genere
  // el constructor por defecto
  POO(int) { }

  // Sin embargo con =default podemos forzar dicha implementación
  POO() = default;
};
```

Esto se puede hacer también en los archivos cpp, lo cual evitará que la implementación de la función se realice a nivel de la cabecera:

POO.h

```
class POO
{
public:
  POO();
};
```

POO.cpp

```
#include "POO.h"

POO::POO() = default;
```

**Herencia**

En caso de herencia, el compilador no va a hacer el esfuerzo por determinar si una clase base va a ser objeto de herencias, por lo que su destructor **nunca** va a ser declarado como virtual. Esto puede provocar comportamientos anómalos en nuestra aplicación.

**Conclusiones**

> es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores cuando usamos setters o getters?

Como norma general, **no**, no es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores, aunque, como ves. Sin embargo hay una larga lista de situaciones en las que será imprescindible, o al menos recomendable, implementar de forma manual dichas funciones.

Un concepto a tener en cuenta es que el hecho de tener *getters* y *setters* es independiente del hecho de implementar los constructores y destructores. Los *getters* y los *setters* nos permiten acceder y modificar el estado del objeto, mientras que la función de los constructores y destructores es garantizar el ciclo de vida del objeto.

Dicho de otra forma. Los *getters* y los *setters* se implementarán en función de las necesidades que tengamos a la hora de utilizar un objeto y los constructores y destructores se implementarán en función del tipo de variables que compongan el estado de un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, NO es estrictamente necesario crearlos, tu puedes llegar a crear una clase sin constructor ni destructor y funcionará perfectamente. Por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Example{
    private:
        int num1;

    public:

    void set_num1(int n){
        this->num1 = n;
    }

    int get_num1(){
        return num1;
    }
};


int main(){
    Example instance;

    instance.set_num1(5);
    cout<<instance.get_num1();


}
```

Si bien es una buena práctica de programación crear el constructor (o constructores, se puede crear más de uno) para poder instanciar la clase y también el destructor.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿es necesario escribir los constructores y destructores cuando usamos setters o getters?

La existencia de *setters* y *getters* no tiene absolutamente ninguna relación con la necesidad de redactar constructores y destructores de un objeto.

Necesitarás redactar un constructor cuando el objeto deba personalizar su construcción, esto puede suceder en casos como:

- El comportamiento del objeto cambiará dependiendo de los parámetros de construcción:

  ```
    class Fecha {
        int anyo = 1900, mes = 1, dia = 1;
    public;
        Fecha(int anyo, int mes, int dia);
        bool es_correcta() const;
    };

    // Abril no tiene 31 días... el objeto queda en un estado no válido.
    Fecha f(1999, 4, 31);

    if (!f.es_correcta()) std::cout << "Error!";
  ```
- El objeto necesita apropiarse de un recurso:

  ```
    class Datos {
        std::ifstream datos;
    public:
        Datos(const std::string &archivo) : datos{archivo} {}
    };

    // El objeto bloqueará el archivo 'Archivo.txt'
    Datos procesar("Archivo.txt");
  ```
- El objeto necesita hacer operaciones especiales:

  ```
    class Objeto {
        int i;
    public:
        Objeto(int *v) : i{*v} {}
    };

    // Es peligroso copiar un puntero, puede ser seguro copiar aquello a lo que apuntan.
    int *i = new int(0b101010);
    Objeto o(i);
  ```

Necesitarás redactar un destructor cuando el objeto deba hacer operaciones al destruirse, en casos como:

- El objeto debe liberar un recurso:

  ```
    class Cosa {
        std::mutex &m;
    public:
        Cosa(std::mutex &m) : m{m} { m.lock(); }
        ~Cosa() { m.unlock(); }
    };
  ```

Observarás que ninguno de los objetos puestos como ejemplo tienen *getter* o *setter*.